# AWS docker on fargate - is it possible to choose different kernel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, linux-kernel, aws-fargate

I need another ubuntu kernel that docker would be run on (on fargete). 
This is needed cause I need to install dependencies that can't be installed on aws kernel in my docker, I actually need generic ubuntu. Is that doable? couldn't find reference to this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Fargate locks you in to the [Fargate platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html), which includes the kernel they choose to use.

> AWS Fargate platform versions are used to refer to a specific runtime environment for Fargate task infrastructure. It is a combination of the kernel and container runtime versions.

If you use the EC2 launch type, as opposed to FARGATE launch type, you will control the underlying EC2 host, and then you may choose whatever OS/kernel you like.